# What is the most efficient way to copy a S3 "folder"?

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I want to find an efficient way to copy an S3 folder/prefix with lots of objects to another folder/prefix on the same bucket. This is what I have tried.

Test data: around `200` objects, around `100 MB` each.

1) `aws s3 cp --recursive`. It took around `150 secs`.

2) `s3-dist-cp`. It took around `59 secs`.

3) `spark & aws jdk, 2 threads`. It took around `440 secs`.

4) `spark & aws jdk, 64 threads`. It took around `50 secs`.

The threads definitely worked, but when it goes to a single thread, the `aws java sdk` approach seems not as efficient the `aws s3 cp` approach. **Is there a single-threaded programming API that can have performance comparable to that of `aws s3 cp`**? Or if there is a better to copy data?

Ideally I would prefer to use programming API to have more flexibility.

Below are the codes I used.

```
  import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}
  import java.net.URI


  def listAllFiles(rootPath: String): Seq[String] = {
    val fileSystem = FileSystem.get(URI.create(rootPath), new Configuration())
    val it = fileSystem.listFiles(new Path(rootPath), true)
    var files = List[String]()

    while (it.hasNext) {
      files = it.next().getPath.toString::files
    }

    files
  }

  def s3CopyFiles(spark: SparkSession, fromPath: String, toPath: String): Unit = {
    val fromFiles = listAllFiles(fromPath)
    val toFiles = fromFiles.map(_.replaceFirst(fromPath, toPath))
    val fileMap = fromFiles.zip(toFiles)

    s3CopyFiles(spark, fileMap)
  }

  def s3CopyFiles(spark: SparkSession, fileMap: Seq[(String, String)]): Unit = {
    val sc = spark.sparkContext
    val filePairRdd = sc.parallelize(fileMap.toList, sc.defaultParallelism)
    filePairRdd.foreachPartition(it => {
      val p = "s3://([^/]*)/(.*)".r
      val s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient()
      while (it.hasNext) {
        val (p(fromBucket, fromKey), p(toBucket, toKey)) = it.next()
        s3.copyObject(fromBucket, fromKey, toBucket, toKey)
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: [aws s3 > is “aws s3 cp” command implemented with multithreads?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36647186/174777)

Comment: there is a scala extension lib for aws s3 https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/s3.html

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Given that "aws s3 cp" is actually multi-threaded, the performance numbers looks reasonable.

Comment: @Vamsi The Akka implementation is still using ```aws java sdk```. There is probably not much room for improvement ? Also, it is much harder to build a distributed application than using Spark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AWS SDK transfer manager is multithreaded; you tell it the block size you want to split the copy up by and it will do it across threads and coalesce the output at the end. Your code shouldn't have to care about how the thread/http pool is working.

Remember that the COPY call isn't doing IO; each thread issues the HTTP request and then blocks awaiting the answer...you can have many, many of them blocked at the same time

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend async approach, for example [reactive-aws-clients](https://github.com/j5ik2o/reactive-aws-clients). You still will be limited to the S3 throttling bandwidth but you won't need brute force of huge number of threads on client side. For example, you could create a Monix app with structure like:

```
val future = listS3filesTask.flatMap(key => Task.now(getS3Object(key))).runAsync
Await.result(future, 100.seconds)
```

Another possible optimization could be using torrent protocol [s3 feature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/S3Torrent.html) if you have multiple consumers, so you can distribute data files across consumers with just one S3 `GetObject` operation per file.